# How can I create a recurring task in Google Tasks?

Tags: google, google-tasks

There's a task that I need to do every Tuesday and Thursday. Is there a way to configure a recurring task in Google Tasks? I can't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of this moment, no. It seems they are working on it, since it ranked [among the top five](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2011/01/top-tasks-for-google-tasks.html) in a "top requests" survey.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I wrote a "simple script" which implements recurrent tasks in Google Tasks.

Published in the Chrome Store: [Recurrent Tasks for GTasks](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/recurrent-tasks-for-gtask/fgmgamfcgnjeficlndkjgelpjplpgdnd)

After installing it you can create a recurrent task by adding recurrence pattern to task notes. In your case:

```
*E 1 W 35
```

Which means "every one week on 3rd and 5th day".

Simple!